# Ignore a dataset if parameter is null

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report comprised of multiple tables/multiple datasets and parameters reporting from two different servers.  One of the parameters can be set to null in which case I need to ignore a particular dataset all together.  Im currently getting an error for that dataset and it's because a null value is being passed for the database name which of course won't work.  I know I can change the visibility but I don't see where I can just ignore the dataset itself. I have the parameter set to allow null values.

Comment: write an if statement into the query so the code will only execute if the param is not null

Comment: Thats actually what I ended doing before I read your comment.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "ignore" a dataset during report execution, all dataset queries are executed every time a report is run. However, you can include code in your dataset query (if the source supports it) such that the dataset does not return any rows based on the value of a certain parameter.

e.g. for a SQL Server source:

```
IF @SomeParameter IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  -- this path returns some rows
  SELECT 
      Col1
    , Col2
  FROM
    SomeTable
  WHERE
    Col1 = @SomeParameter
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  -- this path does not return any rows
  SELECT 
      Col1
    , Col2
  FROM
    SomeTable
  WHERE 
    1=0   -- always false
END
```